# wikipedia scraping with wikipedia 1.4.0: How to skip bad results?

Tags: python-2.7, list, web-scraping, wikipedia-api

I'm using **wikipedia** for python 2.7, to **scrape** articles, using words from very large dataset.

Here's the code:

```
for node_id in top_k:
    human_string = label_lines[node_id]
    score = predictions[0][node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))       


    # Wiki = wikipedia.page(human_string)
    # print (Wiki.content)

    lista.append(human_string)

for i in xrange(5):
    wiki = wikipedia.page(lista[i])
    print (wiki.content)
    a = wiki.content
    #appendowanie = '%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score)
    # appendowanie = str(human_string)
    appendFile = open('/home/inception/wikipedia.txt', 'a')
    appendFile.write('\n\n'+str(i))
    appendFile.write(a.encode("utf-8"))
    appendFile.close()
```

I Want to take 5 items from the list, search it in wikipedia, and scrape whole articles to wikipedia.txt file.
Sometimes wikipedia search gives me an error, due to unknown word from the list:
**example error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "label_image.py", line 68, in <module>
    wiki = wikipedia.page(lista[i])   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 276, in page
    return WikipediaPage(title, redirect=redirect, preload=preload)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 299, in __init__
    self.__load(redirect=redirect, preload=preload)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wikipedia/wikipedia.py", line 345, in __load
    raise PageError(self.title) wikipedia.exceptions.PageError: Page id "gracile crown blackbird" does not match any pages. Try another id!
```

> gracile crown blackbird

**I want to change the script to ignore words which wikipedia scraper can't load**
*Is there's a way to find all wrong words with one script?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try-except as this:

```
try:
    <get the article>
except wikipedia.exceptions.PageError as e:
    if "does not match any pages" in str(e):
        <ignore the error>
    else:
        # Some other error jumped out, so do not ignore it:
        raise
```

Now, this is not 100% sure, because the page's name could be "does not match any pages", theoretically.

So, you would really need to enter the exception catched in variable e and only see the message or if there is the error number or something.

Because I think that PageError() can be raised for more than page not found.

I do not know how is PageError() exception made, but perhaps:

```
e.msg
```

or

```
e.message
```

Should give you the real thing instead of checking in str(e)

Comment: Thank you, I think this is it.
I dont get the `raise` thing, should I put other error messages in `else`?
In if statement I have added the `wiki = wikipedia.page(lista[i+1])` to get the next article.
 I need to code it a little more complexed. There is a kind of error message which gives me a list of possible wikipedia articles. I think there should be an option to catch the first one and read the article.

Comment: You can put: raise e   if it looks better to you. But raise without anything will just raise the error try catched. Go to your Python's site-packages directory, and read wikipedia/exceptions.py to see how PageError() exactly works and what attributes will it have in which condition. There is also the documentation. You can perhaps use wikipedia.search() instead of directly calling pages.